# How to print a variable in client from server in realtime in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have to print in 'live.ejs' a variable from server. It must refresh automatically when variable change its content. The variable is in a loop in nodejs server so no refresh is the problem.

I cannot use sockets. I tried with render but I failed. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: You're looking for Socket.io.

Comment: You should provide your code to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. **Pull:** *(simulates real-time)* After a certain time interval, ask the server for the variable's value. Repeat indefinitely (or until a certain condition is met, your choice)
2. **Push:** *(as real-time as it gets)* Have the Backend notify the Frontend. In order to achieve that, you need to establish a bi-directional communication channel between both parties (or at least from Backend to Frontend in this case). There is no way around it. [Socket.io](https://socket.io) is really easy to set up and has really nice docs with examples.

Since you're using EJS with this, here a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@noufel.gouirhate/build-a-simple-chat-app-with-node-js-and-socket-io-ea716c093088) that talks about how to set up a chat app with Node.js, EJS and Socket.io

Comment: I fixed 50% of my problem with socket.io but now, my client receive socket data from server but it don't update it in realtime. I have to refresh my live page to see the updated socket data. This is the first time when I have problems with sockets. In other projects it works in relatime but now... Thanks for help! This is the code from live page : "var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3002');
    socket.emit('live', 'live client is connected');
    socket.on('live', function(data) {
        //alert(data)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;

    });"

Comment: you're emitting __AND__ listening the same _event. The `socket.on(event)` needs to match what's emitted from your __server__, not the client